# Why doesn't golang have a version number built into go.mod

Tags: versioning, go

I've recently been learning go and the versioning system seems rather odd to me. Most languages / dependency management systems that I'm familiar with (like rust and cargo) have an explicit way to specify a package or module version built into whatever configuration file they use (`Cargo.toml`).

I understand that go does not have something like this built into the `go.mod` file, and instead many projects rely on things like [tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). I haven't been able to find any good explanation for why this design choice was made (but many a tutorial explaining how to do it), and it seems weird give go developers access to a built-in package manager, but also force them to depend on another external tool for such critical functionality.

This design choice makes even less sense to me since you have to specify the versions of dependencies, while also tracking these versions in `go.sum`. Relying both on `go.mod` to manage dependency versions and a VCS to manage specifying the module version seems like a poor design choice, and makes development unnecessarily complex and opaque.

1. Is there a documented decision why they chose this path?
2. What are the benefits of it over the more straightforward approach like cargo?

Comment: [Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/839601)

Comment: @gnat Fair enough, if the answer is "there were ten people in a room, half of them had strong opinions, and there was a back-and-forth argument about it for months on end before a reasonable compromise was struck that left everybody pretty happy" that's fine. I was just hoping there was some RFC or article I had missed somewhere that gave some kind of explanation

Comment: @gnat That being said, I feel like my questions are fairly close the sample questions at the bottom of the linked post to have a concrete answer or be satisfied with a link or have a reasonable scope that can be answered.

Comment: Go was developed by Google as mostly an internal tool. Google has a huge monorepo, they don't manage external dependencies. For years, the primary Go dependency management strategy was to “vendor” (i.e., copy) dependencies into your version control, for example by using git-submodules and checking out a particular commit. Tags are just human-readable names for a commit. Later Go package management tools are mostly just an evolution of that idea. I don't like it either. In contrast, the Rust people tried to get dependency management right from the start. Cargo is truly wonderful.

Comment: @amon thanks! That makes sense, if also annoying that its being so widely adopted and this hasn't really been addressed yet. Either way cargo is indeed great!